# Вибрация (дёргание) элементов в Box2D при использовании Apply Force

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, box2d

Делаю небольшую игру на *JavaScript* с использованием *Box2D* (хотя, думаю язык не важен, так как движок одинаковый, насколько известно, и был экспортирован на *JavaScript*).

Соединяю несколько тел с помощью *Distance Joint*. При создания *joint'а* указываю `frequencyHz = 11` и `dampingRatio = 0` (как я понял, чем меньше `dampingRatio`, тем быстрее элемент вернется в исходное положение, то есть пружина будет жестче, что мне и надо). К каждому телу применяю силу:

```
body.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(0, 5800), body.GetWorldCenter())
```

Это мне нужно для того, чтобы у этих тел была больше гравитация, чем у других.

После создания нескольких элементов, они все начинаю дергаться, вибрировать, как будто им что то не дает покоя, остановится и зафиксироваться в каком-то положении.

Пробовал «играться» с параметрами `frequencyHz` и `dampingRatio` у *joint'а*, и добивался, чтобы конструкция не дергалась, но тогда конструкция кажется менее жесткой и более плавной.

Есть какое-то решение?

Я думаю что конструкция вибрирует из за того что, вес нескольких элементов, и сила применимая к ним, тянут объект вниз, увеличивая длину сустава, при это сустав пытается обратно сжимаьтся в исходное положение, из за этого получается вибрация, так как элемент быстро двигается в разные стороны

Answer (score 3):

При разработке игры сталкивался с похожей проблемой. Решением проблемы стало внедрение проверки на слишком маленькую векторную скорость, при достижении определенных диапазонов, я принудительно останавливал объект устанавливая скорость в 0